# Typescript Interfaces: method that return a generic function

Tags: function, typescript, interface, closures

Someone know how can I define an interface for a class method like:

```
wrap(fn) {
  return function(){
    ... // do something
    fn()
  }
}
```

I'm crashing my head around this, basically how can I define the type of a parameter (and a return value) to be `function`?

Comment: It gives me an error if I do `wrapper = wrap(fn);` and then I try to call `wrapper()`: `error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type 'void' has no compatible call signatures.`

Comment: The type of `wrap` is `(fn: () => void) => () => void` in your example. If it is inside of an object, such as a class instance, the type of that object would be `{ wrap(fn: () => void): () => void }` or `{ wrap: (fn: () => void) => () => void }`

Answer (score 1):

I'm supposing you wanted to return another function that have identical type of `fn`.

```
class Wrapper {

    // generic for any fn, without handling parameter type
    // a return type is not required: tsc infers from `return` statement.
    wrap<T extends Function>(fn: T) {
        return function () {
            // NOTE this version does not handle types of parameters.
            // you will have to use `arguments`
            return fn();
        } as any as T;
    }

    // generic for all unary fn
    // we can have correct type of arg1 in this way
    wrapF1<P1, R>(fn: (arg1: P1) => R) {
        const wrapped = function (arg1: P1) {
            return fn(arg1);
        }
        return wrapped;
    }

    // wrapF2, wrapF3, if you need more
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Jokester, in my case being a `debounce` function, I don't really care about the parameters of the inner fn...

Comment: @teone Good to know that because the `wrapF1` way is far from perfect. For one thing, the parameter name of fn is not preserved. Also it works poor on overloaded functions.